# How do I access an entry in a numerical array in the MongoDB Aggregation Framework?

Tags: mongodb

I'm working with data of the form:

```
word : "afternoon"
counts : [12, 43, 22, 57, 98, 2, 25]

word : "confirmed"
counts : [5, 22, 11, 43, 67, 15, 71]
```

(The MongoDB shell displays the numerical array entries in the form `NumberLong(12)`.)

The question is how, within the MongoDB Aggregation Framework, to obtain the value of the 4th entry (for example) of 'counts', and have it appear in a returned field as a numerical value.  If I could get this then it should be easy to return the 10 words with the largest 4th entry counts, together with those counts. I've tried numerous variations using `$project`, `$unwind`, and `$group`, but I have not been able to figure out how to get the value of that 4th entry as part of the result output.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not currently possible to do this in the aggregation framework.  See here for the open JIRA ticket:  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4589

You'll have to do it using map-reduce code.